# Java SWT: Clear all items in a table before writing

Tags: java, swt

How do I clear a table before writing all the rows?  The data will be completely different every time I hit this code:

```
graphicsMemoryTable.setRedraw(false);
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<graphicsMemory.size() && count<1000; i+=8,count++)
{
    TableItem item = new TableItem(graphicsMemoryTable, SWT.NONE);
    item.setText(graphicsMemory.get(i).toString());
    item.setText(1,graphicsMemory.get(i+1).toString());
    item.setText(2,graphicsMemory.get(i+2).toString());
    item.setText(3,graphicsMemory.get(i+3).toString());
    item.setText(4,graphicsMemory.get(i+4).toString());
    item.setText(5,graphicsMemory.get(i+5).toString());
    item.setText(6,graphicsMemory.get(i+6).toString());
    item.setText(7,graphicsMemory.get(i+7).toString());
}
graphicsMemoryTable.setRedraw(true);
```

**EDIT:**
For reference, calling `removeAll()` worked for me, calling clearAll did not

Comment: Why was it voted down???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`removeAll()` method of `Table` will remove all elements in the table. Here is the javadoc;

```
public void removeAll()
```

> Removes all of the items from the receiver.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `table.clearAll();`

> Clears all the items in the receiver. The text, icon and other
>   attributes of the items are set to their default values. If the table
>   was created with the `SWT.VIRTUAL` style, these attributes
>   are requested again as needed.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this method before posting, but for some reason it would not work.

Comment: This clears the items, as in: it sets their values to empty. The tableitems still exists though, and new items will be added below the empty ones.