# remove all button cell from table?

Tags: java, swt

Is there a way to remove all ***button cell*** from table or determine index of them in table? All rows have remove button for each row it works perfectly but now I need to implement  remove all method  and stucked in these button cell issue. When executed `table.removeAll()`, all data are affected except this `Button`s or `TableEditor`s. Here is the code that I am working on it and image that shows what happens:

`table.remove(index)` or `table.RemoveAll()` methods are not able to effect button, so I use `dispose()` to remove button for each row. ***Any solution to get index of row where located each button would make me more grateful***.

**Note** : added comments where I am trying to implement remove methods.

```
public class Test implements Listener {
private Composite      composite;
private Button         button;
Alarm                  alarm;
private TableViewer    tableViewer;
private Table          table;
private Button         operationButtons;
private Button         removeButtons;
private Button         checkButtons;
private TabFolder      tabFolder;
private String         name;
RestClientAlarmRegions alarms = new RestClientAlarmRegions();
final Point            newSize;

public Test(TabFolder tabFolder) {
    this.tabFolder = tabFolder;
    this.name = "Test";
    TabItem item = new TabItem(this.tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    item.setText(this.name);
    item.setToolTipText(this.name);

    final int insetX = 4, insetY = 4;
    FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
    formLayout.marginWidth = insetX;
    formLayout.marginHeight = insetY;
    composite = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    newSize = composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, true);

    composite.setLayout(formLayout);

    Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.WRAP);
    label.setText("List");

    button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("Remove All");
    button.setSize(new Point(100, 40));
    FormData buttonData = new FormData();
    buttonData.right = new FormAttachment(100, -insetX);
    buttonData.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
    button.setLayoutData(buttonData);
    button.setVisible(true);

    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            if (e.widget instanceof Button) {
                // how to determine index of this buttons or editors to
                // remove in any loop..? also created a for loop for 
                // disposing all button without index but effected only one 
                //  row's buttons.
                removeButtons.dispose();
                checkButtons.dispose();
                operationButtons.dispose();
                table.removeAll();
            }
        }
    });// remove all button listener that works for only row data not
       // buttons.

    tableViewer = new TableViewer(composite, SWT.BORDER);

    table = tableViewer.getTable();

    TableViewerColumn tableColumn1 = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer,
            SWT.CENTER);
    TableViewerColumn tableColumn2 = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer,
            SWT.CENTER);
    TableViewerColumn tableColumn7 = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer,
            SWT.CENTER);
    TableViewerColumn tableColumn8 = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer,
            SWT.CENTER);

    tableColumn1.getColumn().setText("Visibility");
    tableColumn2.getColumn().setText("Description");
    tableColumn7.getColumn().setText("Operation");
    tableColumn8.getColumn().setText("Operation");

    tableColumn1.getColumn().setWidth(80);
    tableColumn2.getColumn().setWidth(140);
    tableColumn7.getColumn().setWidth(80);
    tableColumn8.getColumn().setWidth(80);

    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    FormData tableData = new FormData();
    tableData.left = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
    tableData.right = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
    tableData.top = new FormAttachment(label, insetY);
    tableData.bottom = new FormAttachment(button, -insetY);
    table.setLayoutData(tableData);

    Point size = label.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
    final FormData labelData = new FormData(size.x, SWT.DEFAULT);
    labelData.left = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
    labelData.right = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
    label.setLayoutData(labelData);

    item.setControl(composite);

}

@Override
public void dateReceived(final Alarm alarm) {
    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            final TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
            final TableEditor operationEditors = new TableEditor(table);
            final TableEditor checkEditors = new TableEditor(table);
            final TableEditor removeEditors = new TableEditor(table);
            operationButtons = new Button(table, SWT.PUSH);
            removeButtons = new Button(table, SWT.PUSH);
            checkButtons = new Button(table, SWT.CHECK);

            checkButtons.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, table.getItemHeight());
            checkButtons.setSelection(true);
            checkEditors.grabHorizontal = true;
            checkEditors.minimumHeight = checkButtons.getSize().y;
            checkEditors.minimumWidth = checkButtons.getSize().x;
            checkEditors.setEditor(checkButtons, item, 0);

            removeButtons.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, table.getItemHeight());
            removeButtons.setSelection(true);
            removeButtons.setText("Remove");

            removeEditors.grabHorizontal = true;
            removeEditors.minimumHeight = removeButtons.getSize().y;
            removeEditors.minimumWidth = removeButtons.getSize().x;

            removeEditors.setEditor(removeButtons, item, 3);

            operationButtons.setText("GO");
            operationButtons.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, table.getItemHeight());

            operationEditors.grabHorizontal = true;
            operationEditors.minimumHeight = operationButtons.getSize().y;
            operationEditors.minimumWidth = operationButtons.getSize().x;

            operationEditors.setEditor(operationButtons, item, 2);

            removeButtons.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
                @Override
                public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                    if (e.widget instanceof Button) {

                        MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox(composite
                                .getShell(), SWT.ICON_QUESTION | SWT.YES
                                | SWT.NO);
                        messageBox
                                .setMessage("Do you really want to remove?");
                        int response = messageBox.open();
                        if (response == SWT.YES) {

                            composite.getDisplay().asyncExec(
                                    new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            removeEditors.getEditor()
                                                    .dispose();
                                            operationEditors.getEditor()
                                                    .dispose();
                                            checkEditors.getEditor()
                                                    .dispose();
                                            table.remove(table
                                                    .indexOf(item));
                                            composite.layout(true, true);
                                            composite.setSize(
                                                    composite.getSize().x,
                                                    composite.getSize().y - 1);

                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });// remove buttons operation that works fine for induvidial ,
               // each row data and buttons.

            item.setText(0, "");
            item.setText(1, alarm.getDescription());

        }
    });
}}
```

### [image]

*after removeAll*

[image]

---

**Edit**: Solution but not desired:

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.getChildren();
```

`table.getChildren()` returns an array of children. Now, I am disposing buttons by iterating over this childen array. It works for removing all buttons that are residual from table `removeAll()` method.

```
button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            if (e.widget instanceof Button) {
                for (Control button : table.getChildren()) {
                    button.dispose();
                }
                table.removeAll();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried method table.clearAll? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37720924/2553194

Comment: @RubioRic thank you.I have also tried before. It gives same result as `table.removeAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to create new UI components for each alarm/data you receive, let JFace do it for you, go for an MVC model.

Then all you have to do to implement remove all is to clear the model `alarms.clear()` then ask the view to refresh `tableViewer.refresh()`.

you shoold have sothing like this :

```
   public Test(TabFolder tabFolder) {
        this.tabFolder = tabFolder;
        this.name = "Test";
        TabItem item = new TabItem(this.tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText(this.name);
        item.setToolTipText(this.name);

        final int insetX = 4, insetY = 4;
        FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
        formLayout.marginWidth = insetX;
        formLayout.marginHeight = insetY;
        composite = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
        newSize = composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, true);

        composite.setLayout(formLayout);

        Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.WRAP);
        label.setText("List");

        button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
        button.setText("Remove All");
        button.setSize(new Point(100, 40));
        FormData buttonData = new FormData();
        buttonData.right = new FormAttachment(100, -insetX);
        buttonData.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
        button.setLayoutData(buttonData);
        button.setVisible(true);

        button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                alarms.clear();
                tableViewer.refresh();
            }
        });

        tableViewer = new TableViewer(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

        Table table = tableViewer.getTable();

        TableViewerColumn tableColumn1 = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.CENTER);
        TableViewerColumn tableColumn2 = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.CENTER);
        TableViewerColumn tableColumn7 = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.CENTER);
        TableViewerColumn tableColumn8 = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.CENTER);

        tableColumn1.getColumn().setText("Visibility");
        tableColumn2.getColumn().setText("Description");
        tableColumn7.getColumn().setText("Operation");
        tableColumn8.getColumn().setText("Operation");

        tableColumn1.getColumn().setWidth(80);
        tableColumn2.getColumn().setWidth(140);
        tableColumn7.getColumn().setWidth(80);
        tableColumn8.getColumn().setWidth(80);

        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        FormData tableData = new FormData();
        tableData.left = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
        tableData.right = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
        tableData.top = new FormAttachment(label, insetY);
        tableData.bottom = new FormAttachment(button, -insetY);
        table.setLayoutData(tableData);

        Point size = label.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
        final FormData labelData = new FormData(size.x, SWT.DEFAULT);
        labelData.left = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
        labelData.right = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
        label.setLayoutData(labelData);


        // defaine model
        tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
        tableViewer.setInput(alarms);

        // labels providers
        tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new CellLabelProvider() {

            @Override
            public void update(ViewerCell cell) {

                switch (cell.getColumnIndex()) {
                case 1:
                    cell.setText(" Description "+ cell.getElement().toString());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cell.setText("GO");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cell.setText("Remove");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        // editing support
        tableColumn7.setEditingSupport(new CellEditingSupport(tableViewer){

            @Override
            protected void clicked(Object element) {
                System.err.println("GO clicked");
            }
        });

        tableColumn8.setEditingSupport(new CellEditingSupport(tableViewer){

            @Override
            protected void clicked(Object element) {
                MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox(composite.getShell(), SWT.ICON_QUESTION | SWT.YES | SWT.NO);
                messageBox.setMessage("Do you really want to remove?");
                if (messageBox.open() == SWT.YES) {
                    alarms.remove(element);
                    tableViewer.refresh();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    abstract class CellEditingSupport extends EditingSupport {

        private final TableViewer viewer;
        private CheckboxCellEditor cellEditor;

        public CellEditingSupport(TableViewer viewer) {
            super(viewer);
            this.viewer = viewer;
        }

        @Override
        protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
            if (cellEditor == null) {
                cellEditor = new CheckboxCellEditor(viewer.getTable());
            }
            return cellEditor;  
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object getValue(Object element) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
            clicked(element );
        }

        protected abstract void clicked(Object element) ;
    }
```